# Spark JavaRdd to Dataframe conversion code stops without error

Tags: java, apache-spark, dataframe, rdd

I am trying to convert a `JavaRDD<PageRankCase>` class to a `DataFrame` so that I can later save it into a `parquet` file but the code execution stops at the `createDataFrame` function call, it gives null when I handle the exception. Here's my class.

```
public static class PageRanksCase implements Serializable{

    private String node;
    private Double importance; 


    public void setNode(String node) { this.node = node; }
    public void setImportance(Double importance) { this.importance = importance; }

    public String getNode(String node) { return this.node; }
    public Double getImportance(String node) { return this.importance; }
}
```

And this the code I am trying to run to convert the class into `DataFrame`.

```
try{
    JavaRDD<PageRanksCase> finalData = GetTopNNodes(pairedrdd);
    System.out.println("coming here");
    DataFrame finalFrame = Service.sqlCtx().createDataFrame(finalData,PageRanksCase.class);
    System.out.println("coming here too");
    finalFrame.write().parquet(rdfanalyzer.spark.Configuration.storage() + "sib200PageRank.parquet");
}
catch(Exception e)
{ 
  System.out.println(e.getMessage());  // gives null here.
}
```

It does print `coming here` but it's not printing `coming here too` and also not giving any errors. Here's how I convert my JavaPairRDD to JavaRDD.

```
public static JavaRDD<PageRanksCase> GetTopNNodes(JavaPairRDD<String,Double> pairedrdd){

    return pairedrdd.map(new Function<Tuple2<String,Double>, PageRanksCase>() {

        @Override
        public PageRanksCase call(Tuple2<String, Double> line) throws Exception {
            PageRanksCase pgrank  = new PageRanksCase();
            pgrank.setImportance(line._2);
            pgrank.setNode(line._1());
            return pgrank;
        }
    });
}
```

Anybody has any idea whats going on here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up re-implementing the code, using the example mentioned on [Spark website](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#creating-datasets).